# How to get html from docx file using node js with images(png and jpeg)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mammoth

i am using mammoth library it is converting `docx` to `html` images are not converting in `png` or `jpeg`. it is converting them in image.

```
contentType: image/x-emf
image.contentType: image/x-wmf
var options = {

        convertImage: mammoth.images.dataUri(async function (image) {
            return image.read("base64").then(async function (imageBuffer) {
                let src = "data:" + imageBuffer.contentType + ";base64," + imageBuffer

                return {
                    src
                };
            });
        })

    };
    mammoth.convertToHtml({ path: docxFilePath }, { ...options })
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log('result:', result)
            var html = result.value; // The generated HTML

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error:', error)
            console.error(error);
        });
```